# PTC thingworx : config.json.booted

Tags: thingworx

Folks, 
I am getting error while starting the wsems @ 443 port on windows 10 machine.

when I type wsems in cmd (with admin), I get following error:

```
C:\Users\<path> microserver>wsems
[INFO ] 2018-10-05 10:27:27,617 wsems: Using config file: C:\Users\<path>\Desktop\Thingworkx\Thingworx microserver\etc\config.json
[FORCE] 2018-10-05 10:27:27,617 wsems: Starting up ....
[ERROR] 2018-10-05 10:27:27,617 jsonConfigurator::initialize: Error parsing JSON.
[ERROR] 2018-10-05 10:27:27,617 Main: Error initializing configurator with C:\Users\<path>\Desktop\Thingworkx\Thingworx microserver\etc\config.json
[WARN ] 2018-10-05 10:27:27,617 Main: Trying .booted config file
[ERROR] 2018-10-05 10:27:27,617 jsonConfigurator::initialize: Error reading file. Error: No such file or directory [C:\Users\<path>\Desktop\Thingworkx\Thingworx microserver\etc\config.json.booted]
[ERROR] 2018-10-05 10:27:27,617 Main: Error initializing configurator with C:\Users\<path>\Desktop\Thingworkx\Thingworx microserver\etc\config.json.booted
[WARN ] 2018-10-05 10:27:27,617 Main: Failed to load .booted config file.  Reverting back to original.
[ERROR] 2018-10-05 10:27:27,632 Main: Failed to load any configuration file.  Exiting...
```

can anyone help me out with this, how to get around with .booted file error?

Comment: The `config.json.booted` file stores the last successful `wsems` configuration. When the `config.json` file has errors, `wsems` does a fallback and tries to start-up using this booted configuration. In your case it seems that you have not yet had a successful configuration and thus don't have any booted file.Check your `config.json` for syntax and formatting errors. Else paste your 'config.json' here so that someone can have a look.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, error indicate that there is issue with your config.json file and non-availability of .booted config file which will be generated upon successful startup & configuration.

Comment: kindly consider adding more details in your answer and kindly don't add name in your answer as the profile picture and name of the author is already always there.